# Overusing INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

We have a table which contains a weather forecast. Each point is at a LAT/LON junction.  To get the temperature at a station, we combine the four points surrounding the station.

The way I am currently doing this is to use INNER JOINS.  This results in the tblLoad table being scanned four times.  There are indices so it's okay speedwise but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it.

```
UPDATE 
    G
SET 
    G.TMP_850 = (((V.WEIGHT_A * L1.fValue + V.WEIGHT_B * L2.fValue) + V.WEIGHT_C * L3.fValue) + V.WEIGHT_D * L4.fValue - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32.0
FROM
    tblGFS G
    INNER JOIN
    tblStations S ON G.szICAO = S.szICAO
    INNER JOIN
    tblVertex_025 V ON V.szICAO = S.szICAO
    INNER JOIN
    tblLoad L1 ON L1.iCoordinate = V.A 
    INNER JOIN
    tblLoad L2 ON L2.iCoordinate = V.B 
    INNER JOIN
    tblLoad L3 ON L3.iCoordinate = V.C 
    INNER JOIN
    tblLoad L4 ON L4.iCoordinate = V.D
```

Comment: you said there are indices but you are not even using them. there is no issue with using multiple inner joins as long as it outputs your desired result

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the tblLoad has a key which includes the iCoordinate so that the entire table doesn't have to be scanned.